# Angular 4 unsupported media type

Tags: angular, jersey, dropwizard, http-status-code-415

So in the backend I have dropwizard and I want to reach out to my /user/register route..

code:

```
@Path("/user/register")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response register(UserRB userRB) {

    String salt = BCrypt.gensalt(16);
    Response response;
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setName(userRB.getName());
    newUser.setMonths(new ArrayList<>());
    newUser.setPassword(BCrypt.hashpw(userRB.getPassword(), salt));
    newUser.setSalt(salt);

    for (User user : Ebean.find(User.class).findList()) {
        if (user.getName().equals(newUser.getName())) {
            return  Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
    }

    Ebean.save(newUser);
    response = Response.ok(newUser).status(Response.Status.CREATED).build();
    return response;
}
```

And with an angular app I want to make a post request with the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {User} from './user';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class RegisterService {

private headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' });
private options =  new RequestOptions(this.headers);

constructor(private http: Http) { }

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
console.error('An error just happened: ', error);
return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}

register(name: String, password: String): Promise<User> {

return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/timelogger/user/register',
  JSON.stringify( { name: name, password: password } ), this.options)
  .toPromise()
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch(this.handleError);
}

}
```

And I get as a response a 415 http code.. Unsupported media type.. and this..

```
key:"content-type"
value:"Content-Type"
```

Comment: Don't set the content-type header. Don't stringify to JSON. Just send the object, and Angular will do both for you. Also, `{ name: name, password: password }`can be reduced to `{ name, password }` in ES6 / TypeScript. And finally, your then() callback transform the promise of response to a promise of undefined. You probably don't want that.

Comment: For the record, your code should have been: `new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers});`

Comment: @JBNizet what do you mean by returning a promise of undefined?

Comment: Your register() method is supposed to be returning a Promise<User>, but it returns a Promise<undefined>. If the caller does `service.register(...).then(user -> console.log(user))`, undefined will be printed. The collback should be `response => response.json()`.

Comment: Okay, understood. Thank you very much again!